# What are the installation requirements for building with cygport?

Tags: bash, cygwin, development-environment, prerequisites

I am trying to build bash from source using cygport in Cygwin, but my build is failing to do basic command substitution.

I don't mean to distract with the particular error I am seeing in the bash build, as I am confident the fault is something to do with the prerequisite packages I have or have not installed, but here it is in case there's a clue here:

```
% echo $(echo hiya)
bash: command substitution: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 9: `echo hiya )'
```

Note that variants on this do work as intended:

```
% echo $(echo hiya
> )
hiya
```

```
% echo `echo hiya`
hiya
```

But I'm pretty sure this is just a distraction.  In theory, if I download the source for any Cygwin package that I'm using successfully in binary form already, I should be able to rebuild that package from source and get much the same behaviour, no?

But in fact, it isn't clear to me how to determine what those prerequisite packages are, both for the development environment in general and those specific to the bash package.  I couldn't find any references to prerequisites inside of the bash.cygport file, for example.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: prerequisite for binary packages are determined at build time. Maintainers can add some more in cygport if needed with `package_REQUIRES`. The full list of requirement for building are seldom reported, it is a time consuming activity of little value for maintainers.

Comment: `% echo` looks strange. what type of shell are you using ? Cygport is a bash tool

Comment: @matzeri I'm using bash.

I got in touch with the bash maintainer, and it sounds like the version of bison I'm using is just struggling with parsing, and maybe the cygport needs to be updated to reflect that.

Comment: The bison version on cygwin is 3.0.4 of 2015. It seems that from 2018 the bison authors decided the release a lot of new versions https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bison/. You can ask, on the cygwin mailing list, the cygwin package maintainer of bison for an updated version. Cygport has no relevance on it.